# PostgreSQL insert or return id

Tags: sql, postgresql

I'm trying to insert or return id of existing value in case of uniqueness conflict (the data is already there).

I'm guessing it could be something like this, but can't quite get it to return the actual ID

```sql
INSERT INTO my_table (my_column) VALUES ('my value') 
ON CONFLICT DO NOTHING
RETURNING ID;
```

where `my_column` has a unique constraint.

Any ideas?

Comment: For context, this would be used as part of a nested insert of a datum into multiple normalized tables

Comment: do you have a unique constraint on your table for that column?